# Data Mining - K nearest neighbor

Tags: machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor

This is my homework. I'm not asking you to do my homework here, I need a hint to keep going.

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]

I know what is K nearest neighbor algorithm however I always seen it on graphs not like this. Can you guys tell me what I should do? I've been trying to figure out how to start doing this but I could not. I would appreciate a small hint from you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment helps you understand the steps in KNN. 
KNN is based on distances. Find the K nearest neighbors and then maybe vote for a classification problem.

Your training data can be considered as (x1,x2, y) : age and profit are features (x1, x2) while BUY or NOT BUY is the label/output y.

To apply Knn you need to calculate the distance, which is based on features. Since the two features share different units ( year, USD), you should convert them into non-unit features which is called normalization, part 4.1 in your handout. After that, the feature vector will look like (-0.4,-0.8). The number should be between -1 and 0 if the suggested formula in part 4.1 is used.

Then use the normalized feature to calculate the distances (Euclidean in the handout) between every training data point and your interested company ( normalized as well).  This is required in 4.2.

Last step should be to pick K nearest neighbor and decide BUY or NOT BUY judging from the outputs of those neighbors. ( a simple voting maybe?)